# Is there any way to connect cypress tests with azure devops test cases?

Tags: cypress

I'm looking for a way to connect cypress tests with azure devops test cases? Like on the image below

[image: test explorer association]

Anyone found some workaround? Like calling cypress tests from mstest framework for example.